If $f$ is entire with $|f(z)| \leq$ $e^{c|z|}$ then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1+\left|a_n\right|\right)^{-\alpha}<\infty$ for $\alpha>1$
Let $c>0$. Suppose that $f$ is an entire function such that $|f(z)| \leq$ $e^{c|z|}$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$. Let $a_1, a_2, \ldots$ be the zeros of $f$, listed with appropriate multiplicity. I would like to show that for all $\alpha>1$,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1+\left|a_n\right|\right)^{-\alpha}<\infty
$$
I know that by Hadamard, $h\le \lambda \le 1$, thus the genus $h$ is either 0 or 1. If it is zero, then $1/|a_n|^{h+1}$ is summable for any $h\ge 0$ and if it is 1, $1/|a_n|^{h+1}$ is summable for any $h \ge 1$. We can conclude that in any case, $1/|a_n|^{\alpha}$ is summable when $\alpha \ge 2$ How do I extend this range of convergence to $1<\alpha<2$?

apply Jensen to conclude that in the disc of radius $R$ there are at most $aR$ roots for a fixed $a>0$ so a comparison with the integral $\int_1^{\infty}x^{-\alpha}dx$ gives you the result

Can you give me some feedback on my attempt below? I was trying to bound the number of zeros in the annuli $R-1<|z|<R$ with Jensen, but I don't think it's possible actually.

you need to bound them in $|z| <R$ and use the integral test

I will try to formulate an answer with the help of Conrad's outline. Assuming $f(0)\neq 0$ for simplicity, Jensen tells us that for $(a_k)_{k=1}^{n(R)}$ the zeros of $f$ in the disk of radius $R$
$$n(R)\le \sum_{k=1}^{n(R)} \log(R/|a_k|)\le \log(1/|f(0)|) + c R,$$
from which we conclude that there is at most a constant number $c$ of zeros in the annuli $\{R-1\le |z|\le R\}$ for all $R>1$ (I actually am not sure if we can show this).
Now, we use that we can write the sum of over zeros as
$$\sum_{M=1}^{\infty } \sum_{M\le |a_n|\le M+1} \frac{1}{|a_n|^\alpha}\asymp\sum_{M=1}^{\infty } \frac{c}{M^\alpha}$$
which converges if $\alpha>1$.
